# ASP.NET Web Api (REST): Authentication using the users credentials or a token? Leave "Register new user" resource password free?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, wcf-rest, asp.net-authentication

I am trying to create a REST service using asp.net web api and everything is working fine but I have now come across what to do with authentication.

I am a little confused of where to start, here is what I have been thinking.

I have an REST api that consist of a number of resources, each resource will need the user to be registered, so what is the best action for doing this? Should I just send the username and password in the header on each call to the service so I can authenticate on the server using

> AuthorizationFilterAttribute

I should at least encrypt it though? I would be interested to know what others are doing, I know there is  a concept of creating a token (which I presume will be short-lived) so hence the user would authenticate and then would receive a token, this token would then be sent on further calls to the service. So how would I handle the problem when the token expires?

I also have a resource that is used to register a new user, actually the only things that will be calling this is my clients (Android, iPhone). SO should I leave it FREE of any authentication methods or put a hard coded password or something similar so that at least nobody else can register new users? Bearing in mind that the service will be public on the internet.

I just don't seem to be able to find the correct way of doing this, I certainly want to try and get it right the first time so I don't have to refactor the service completely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following link appears to cover some sensible DIY options http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/. The "Tokens based on Public/Private Keys" section covers an approach I have used effectively in the past and would maybe be of assistance to you.

At the moment though I am using http://identityserver.codeplex.com/ the Thinktecture IdentityServer with OAuth bearer tokens ("Resource Owner Password Credential" grant type)... I am finding this a very good set of code and examples to work from and have IOS clients obtaining tokens and calling the WebApi.

If you really must secure your registration screen you could maybe use client certificates installed on the devices to authenticate... again the Thinktecture service could help here https://identity.thinktecture.com/idsrv/docs/default.htm?RequestingatokenusingOAuth2.html. Although if you registration process is secure [What are best practices for activation/registration/password-reset links in emails with nonce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066611/what-are-best-practices-for-activation-registration-password-reset-links-in-emai) e.g. email confirmations and activations etc. it may be safe to leave publicly accessible - this all depends on your business requirements and desired sign up workflow.

You should at least use Transport Level security SSL but as you suggest message level security e.g. encrypting any tokens is very advisable - the OAuth spec has something to say about this http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html#mitigation.

Regarding expiring tokens - we tend to expire our tokens with the same frequency as our password changing policy; although keeping the validity time down is important (to minimise impact of token theft) and a consideration to balance against your requirements. OAuth has the concept of refresh tokens [Why Does OAuth v2 Have Both Access and Refresh Tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487991/why-does-oauth-v2-have-both-access-and-refresh-tokens) some debate and links around this topic here, we are not currently using this approach as the ID server we are using doesn't currently support this.

Keeping your tokens safe is also a consideration e.g. we are using the KeyChain in IOS, but also think about Mobile Device Management policies if possible as if these tokens or passwords are one the device they could be stolen, perhaps look into jailbreak detection, lock screen enforcement etc.

Comment: Thanks Mark, i will take a look, this has given me quite a bit to look at.. Thanks for all the help